# In android ellipsize text view between buttons

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, ellipsis

I've looked at many posts on similar subject but couldn't find the answer to this problem... I use a RelativeLayout to have a button on the left, a button on the right and text in the middle. If the text is too long I use ellipsize (see XML below). The problem is that when the text is long it also cuts the BEGINNING of the code (see image). I can fix that by using android:gravity="center_vertical" instead of "center", but then when the text is short it becomes left-justified. I want it centered. Any hint ?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftbutton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/back_chevron_icon"
        android:background="@color/transparent" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightbutton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/back_chevron_icon"
        android:background="@color/transparent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sometext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftbutton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rightbutton"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: with android:gravity:"center_vertical]

What I want is shown in the 2 pictures below. I can achieve that only by changing  the gravity from center to center_vertical and vice versa.

[image: long text ok]

[image: shor text ok]

Comment: try using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for textView

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Comment: so you want to animate your textview ??

Comment: @ArpitPatel I want to be able to change the TextView text.

Comment: i don't understand you mean change your textview to center no matter how long it is??

Comment: can you add screenshot what you want so i can better understand.??

Comment: @ArpitPatel Please see the screenshots I added above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128458/discussion-between-arpit-patel-and-drmad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the code in the initial post WORKS !
It is the Design simulator in Android Studio that actually does not work and shows the (wrong) text layout as in my initial picture. Thank you @#*%! Android Studio developers... I wasted several hours of my time thanks to you...

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Use `android:gravity="center"` on your TextView instead of `android:gravity="center_vertical"` and also use `layout_toEndOf` / `layout_toStartOf` attributes with `layout_toRightOf` and `layout_toLeftOf`

Comment: Please read the original post again. I explained why gravity="center" does not work for me. And the other suggestions don't change anything. So it's not "Simple".

Answer (score 0):

I Just change few tages from your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftbutton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightbutton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sometext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftbutton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rightbutton"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"

        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="Long " />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Comment: Your answer does not help. I want to use TextView. And I should be able to.

Comment: I just chagen android:gravity="center_vertical" from you code Just use android:gravity="center"from textview

Comment: I think you have not read what I wrote. I did that before posting the question. And I explain in my post that it does not work in all cases. Hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can add multiple attribute using **pipe**

like this

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `maxWidth` at your target TextView.